# SUM function in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel:

> EDITED: image reloaded

[image]

Product 1 consist of Item A-E, Product 2 consist of Item B, D & E, Product 3 consist of Item A-F.

$E$3-$E$7, $E$9-$E$11, $E$13-$E$18 are formulated to calculate the price of individual Item based on cost and pieces sold.

Is it possible to sum automatically at $E$2, $E$8 and $E$12 where there is no item (ie Column A-D for data entry, Column E fully formulated)?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't make it clear in the example. I may have few products in the same day.

Comment: Maybe have another column called 'Product No' and subtotal on that using the date.

Comment: Why not a pivot table?

Comment: pnuts, Anthony Sherratt & Mark Fitzgerald, thanks for all of your suggestions. pnuts, I have tried Subtotal. It was unable to update simultaneously when New Product and Item were added. I have to Remove Subtotal and perform Subtotal again. The Grand Total will be relocated further down each time I removed and performed Subtotal. Anthony Sherratt & Mark Fitzgerald, I have also tried your suggestions. However, it was also unable to update simultaneously when New Product and Item were added. I'll look for other solution. Thanks anyway.